# Hi. I'm trying to use the meta tag maximum-scale so the user can't enlarge the size of the viewport

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use the meta tag maximum-scale so the user can't enlarge the size of the viewport.
My code is down below. However, if I open this file with chorme, I can still use the mouse wheel to enlarge the viewport up to 500%, or reduce it down to 25%. How should I fix this problem?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"
    />
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      #container {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background: #f7f7f7;
      }

      #header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 60px;
        background: #d1d1d1;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="header"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? I am worried about accessibility (for those of us who need to enlarge things to read them for example).

Answer (score 0):

from what  I have understood reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag) it works on devices that render pages in a virtual window or viewport like mobile screens, and your code works fine, I tried it in chrome dev tools setting the device to "Iphne XR" and emulating zooming by holding `Shift` + mouse click and drag across the viewport
I haven't been able to zoom in or out.